# Display or hide custom tab on product page depending on variable

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide a display or not display a tab on the single product page depending on the value of $sizeGridNumber. So if this value is 1 or empty, I want the tab not to display. I return an empty array, but it generates errors.

```
/*Customise additional-information tab (Size Grid)*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wpb_custom_additional_information_tab', 98 );
function wpb_custom_additional_information_tab( $tabs ) {
    global $post;
    // var_dump($post->ID);
    $sizeGridNumber = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_selectsizeguide', true );
    $sku = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_sku', true );
    // echo '<br/>';
    // var_dump($sizeGridNumber);
    // print_r($sizeGridNumber);
    // var_dump($sku);
 //    print_r($sku);
    if ( $sizeGridNumber == 1 || $sizeGridNumber == "") {
        echo "on passe";
        return array();
    } else {
        $tabs['additional_information']['callback'] = 'wpb_custom_additional_information_tab_content'; // Custom additional_information callback
        return $tabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the error? the code seems fine.

Comment: I found the solution I did : `unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
     return $tabs;`

Comment: Exactly , in filter you should not return the empty , it affect the whole hooks chain

Comment: I have explained @Louis as a answer so it will helpful for other developers, Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
return array();
```

I did

```
unset( $tabs['additional_information'] );
return $tabs;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not return the empty array like doing in the in [Actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Action),

[Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Filter) are called before the execution and reference variable passed to your function, so if you return the empty value then whole hook chain breaks So you should only do the necessary changes to that var and **return** it back.

Derived from @Louis Answer

Instead of returning

```
return array();
```

Make the needed the changes in the `$tabs` var and return it back.